# How do I convert a JSON array to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am grabbing a string from a database that looks like this

```
[{"messageContent":"Good morning Christine! My name is Oso, it\u0027s 
beary nice to meet you 
:3","msgType":"MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED","statusCode":0,"timeString":"10:31"}, 
{"messageContent":"Good morning Christine! My name is Oso, it\u0027s 
beary nice to meet you 
:3","msgType":"MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED","statusCode":0,"timeString":"10:31"}
```

It began as an ArrayList but I had to convert it into a string to store in in the database.

I need to convert it back. I had was going to use this function but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public static ArrayList<ChatMessage> fromString(String value) {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
}
```

I get this error when I try to run the function.

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to create an `ArrayList` of `String`, but you have OBJECTS, not strings in your JSON. Try changing this line:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
```

To something like this:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ChatMessage>>() {}.getType();
```

Assuming `Gson` knows how to deserialize your `ChatMessage` class, that should work.

Comment: You would think it would at least attempt to do Object.toString

Comment: thank you. I had played arround with the function and forgot to change String back to ChatMessage

Answer (score 0):

1. Your database string is missing a JSON array closing bracket `]` at the end.
2. `gson` type parameter is wrong. You require a `ArrayList<ChatMessage>` but you used `ArrayList<String>`.

Replace

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
```

With

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ChatMessage>>() {}.getType();
```